# IOError: File not open for reading python

Tags: python, file, io

This is what I have so far, everything I try keep stating that the file isn't open? Is there any basic way to fix this?

```
liNames = []
while 1 == 1:
    liNames += [raw_input("Tell me a name. Type DONE(all caps) if done entering:")]
    if "DONE" in liNames:
        break

del liNames[-1]

print liNames

name_file = open("names.txt","w")
line = name_file.writelines(liNames)
for line in name_file:
    print line
name_file.close()
```

Comment: Try opening the file ;-)

Comment: I think you forgot to post the code...

Comment: sorry first time here

Comment: You opened the file for writing (`"w"`).  You can't read from a file opened for writing.  Close the file after writing to it, then open it again for reading (`"r"`, or just omit the file-mode argument - it defaults to reading).

Comment: try to open file with `open("names.txt","r+")` instead

Comment: @zybjtu, that won't work unless they learn how to `seek()` too.  Better for a beginner to close the file and open it again.

Comment: @TimPeters Yeah, you're right. I should say try to re-open the file. Like `name_file = open("names.txt","w")` `line = name_file.writelines(liNames)` `name_file.close()` `name_file = open("names.txt","r") for ....`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: thanks for all your help to all of you, now why doesn't it print on multiple lines? lol

Comment: I think this should print in multiple lines..

Comment: I see the problem, it's not saving to the file in multiple lines not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

To be concrete about what the comments have suggested, after this line:

```
line = name_file.writelines(liNames)
```

insert these new lines:

```
name_file.close()
name_file = open("names.txt", "r") # or plain open("names.txt")
```

With more experience, you'll write this as:

```
with open("names.txt","w") as name_file:
    name_file.writelines(liNames)
with open("names.txt") as name_file:
    for line in name_file:
        print line
```

With even more experience ;-), you'll learn how to open a file for both reading *and* writing.  But that's trickier, and *especially* tricky for text files on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Solving your error:

You're only opening it in writing mode, to read it, open it in read mode:

```
name_file = open("names.txt", "r")
```

Or just:

```
name_file = open("names.txt")
```

Since python opens file in reading mode by default.

So the steps are:

1. open the file in write mode.
2. write to it.
3. close it.

After that, to read the file:

1. re-open it in read mode.
2. read it.
3. close it.

In short, like this:

```
name_file = open("names.txt","w")
line = name_file.writelines(liNames)
name_file.close()
name_file = open("names.txt")

for line in name_file:
    print line
name_file.close()
```

To make thing look neater, use the `with` statement (It will automatically close the file)

Like this:

```
with open('names.txt', 'w') as file_name:
    line = name_file.writelines(liNames)

with open('names.txt', 'r') as file_name:
    for line in name_file:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Peters said, when you open the file in your code, you open it for writing. When you finish writing, the file remains open in this mode until you call "close()" in the last line.

As pointed, you should do this (one possible way):

```
name_file = open("names.txt","w")
line = name_file.writelines(liNames)
name_file.close()

name_file = open("names.txt")
for line in name_file:
    print line
name_file.close()
```

Another way is using `with` statement:

```
with open("nmes.txt", "w") as name_file:
    name_file.writelines(liNames)
```

This closes the file automatically when the `with` block finishes.